# Matching between annotation and processor

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, annotations, annotation-processing

How can I find a corresponding processor for an annotation? For example, consider @Before annotation from JUnit.

```
Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Before {
}
```

I used IDEA, By searching for @Before it finds only usages. And breakpoint at annotation is not possible.

Comment: I would right click on the `Before` and select "Find Usages" in my IDE.

Comment: What do you mean by annotation ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, does it find the place where it is processed and not used?

Comment: @singe31, Java annotation.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov It find everywhere in your source that it is used, it won't find source if you don't have it.  You can assume it is in the junit source somewhere, and as long as you can see that e.g. via maven, it will find where it is used for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to find processors using breakpoints, it's a little complicated though. This article describes how to set breakpoints on annotation processors:
[Debugging an annotation processor in every IDE](http://www.pingtimeout.fr/2012/10/debugging-annotation-processor-in-every.html)

Basically you have to set some compiler flags to make the JVM used by the compiler run in debug mode:

```
-J-Xdebug -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

I've tried setting the flags in eclipse as described in the article but it seems this option has been removed. I don't know if this is possible in IDEA.

If you don't want to debug a particular processor, you could try setting a breakpoint on the `init` method of `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` - though it is not guaranteed that every processor will use this abstract class, some might have their own implementation of `javax.annotation.processing.Processor`. It is also not guaranteed that annotations are handled only by processors, the compiler might handles some annotations directly. Annotation can also be handled on runtime, you might need to add some breakpoints in the Annotation class itself.

To set breakpoints in standard library classes, I've had to [attach the source in eclipse](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-attach-jdk-source-code/).

Comment: Actually solution by Peter Lawrey works. I was able to find the processor by searching the usages in libraries.